# WAMP forbidden 403 al descargar un archivo via AJAX

Tags: apache

al intentar descargar un archivo via ajax, apache me esta retornando forbidden 403, al parecer ese error es debido a los privilegios de la carpeta.

js ajax request

```
function Ajax() {
    "use strict";
    var operacion = 'BackupDB';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '../logica/backup-restore.logic.php?operacion='+operacion,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('button[name=BtnBackUp]').text(' Generando...').prepend('<i class="fa fa-gear fa-spin"></i>');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data) {
                window.location.assign('../backup/'+data);
                toastr.success('Respaldo Generado con Exito!.');
            } else {
                toastr.error('Error al Generar Respaldo :( .');
            }
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('button[name=BtnBackUp]').text(' Generar').prepend('<i class="fa fa-download fa-lg"></i>');
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

como pueden ver se hace un window.loacation.assign() para apuntar la dirección del archivo que se va a descargar.

Answer (score 0):

Editar el archivo phpmyadmin.conf:

Ubicarse en *C:/wamp/alias/phpmyadmin.conf* y sustituir al final:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

**sustituir por:**

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Y en el archivo httpd.conf, que se encuentra en *C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\conf\httpd.conf*, sustituir el código:

```
AllowOverride None
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
por el siguiente:

AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

**Después de hacer esos cambios, reiniciar WAMP.**

Comment: Solo aparece esta linea  <Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory> es apache 2.4.17

Comment: Coloca la primera opción que te doy,  `AllowOverride All Order allow,deny
Allow from all `

Comment: sigue el error.

Comment: Ya edité completamente mi respuesta, trata de hacerlo igual.

Comment: lo siento no funciona. Toma en cuenta que uso WAMP64 y Windows 10

Comment: trata de hacerlo en modo administrador, abre el bloc de notas en modo administrador y desde ahí abre el archivo que @x4mp73r te comenta

Answer (score 0):

1. Da click izquierdo en el ícono de WAMP junto al reloj.
2. Ubicate en Apache.
3. Ve a Alias directories
4. Selecciona tu carpeta, ejemplo http://localhost/tuCarpeta
5. Selecciona Edit Alias

Todo lo que esté dentro remplazalo por estas líneas.

```
Alias /miAlias/ "c:/wamp/www/tuCarpeta/" 

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/tuCarpeta/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Quizá difiera en las rutas, pero es la mima ideología.
Espero te sirva.
Debes de tener ya creado el alias, si no sabes como, responde :)